# Header misalignment

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a problem with jQuery DataTables, the problem is that when a table has horizontal scroll bar, and the width of the data table is increased, then the header of the data table is not aligned properly with the body of the data table.

This is the datatable before resize the width, it is normal:
[image: This is the datatable before resize the width, it is normal!]

This is the datatable after resize the width, it has misaligned headers:
[image: This is the datatable after resize the width, it has un-aligned heders]

Here is the code I use, it is in ASP.NET:

```
             <div Class="dataTable_wrapper">
            <Table Class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-UserProfiles">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">User Id</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Full Name</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Phone Number</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Email Address</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Branch Code</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Account Locked</th>
                        <th Class="text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">Account Status</th>
                        <th width="80" Class="text-center">Amend</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                   <% For i As Integer = 0 To ALUserProfiles.Count - 1%> 
                         <% Response.Write("<tr Class=""odd gradeX"">")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td style=""white-space: nowrap""><b>" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserId & "</b></td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserFullName & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserPhoneNumber & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserEmailAddress & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserBranchCode & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td Class=""text-center"" style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & IsAccountLockedOut(ALUserProfiles(i)) & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td Class=""text-center"" style=""white-space: nowrap"">" & ALUserProfiles(i).AccountStatus & "</td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("    <td Class=""text-center""><a class=""btn btn-info"" href=""AmendUserProfile.aspx?UserId=" & ALUserProfiles(i).UserId & """ role=""button"">Amend</a></td>")%> 
                         <% Response.Write("</tr>")%> 
                    <% Next%>

                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTables-UserProfiles').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "order": [[1, "asc"]]
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have any demo(fiddle, code snippet) using your code?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I could not get Responsive to work when scrollX is enabled. If possible, try setting scrollX to false. Then you may have to call columns.adjust() as well as response.recalc().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    yourDataTable = $('#dataTables-UserProfiles').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        scrollX: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "order": [[1, "asc"]]
    });
}).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();

$(window).resize(function() {
    yourDataTable.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
});
```